I'm trying to achieve this kinda grainy color mixing material texture
Specifically really love the way that the colors blend softly and have a kind of cloudy grainy mix to them. But also theres some variety and randomness to them that I can't really achieve with a color ramp since the color ramp has a very set order to colors.
anyone have any idea how i can achieve this??



I think i got it!
The main "gradient" is actually just a noise texture/Multifractal color output.
Using the separated color channels as a mask. In this case the red channel.
using another noise texture > detail socket of the main color noise texture node.
Using layer weight as a way to modify kind of do an "event horizon" style warping of the color as it approaches the visible edges of the mesh object.
